# How to use queryString in the nodejs client for fusionauth?

Tags: fusionauth

I am using the following code to get all users. It works with the Java client but is giving the following error

`{ code: '[invalid]', api_1    |   message: 'You must specify either the [ids], [queryString], [email] or [username] property for a GET request.' }`

What I am trying

```
    let requestJSON = {}
    requestJSON.queryString = "*";
    client.searchUsersByQueryString(requestJSON).then(handleResponse).catch(handleResponse);

    function handleResponse (clientResponse) {
        console.log(clientResponse.errorResponse.generalErrors[0]);
    }
```

Also for some reason, it is assuming this to be a GET Request.

I have already tried doing the same using Postman and it doesn't work. I am using FusionAuth 1.5.0 everywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The client library uses a `POST` request with a JSON body to perform the search. See the `POST /api/user/search` API documentation here https://fusionauth.io/docs/v1/tech/apis/users#search-for-users

Try this instead:

```
let requestJSON = {
  search: {
    queryString: "*"
  }
};


client.searchUsersByQueryString(requestJSON).then(handleResponse).catch(handleResponse);

function handleResponse (clientResponse) {
  console.log(clientResponse.errorResponse.generalErrors[0]);
}
```

Comment: I don't know how I missed the "search.____". Thanks really.

Comment: Also why did you add the additional "search" in the JSON? I really thinking in terms of API design but couldn't find any reason.

Comment: This is a pattern we utilize for all of our APIs, in this particular case it is perhaps less useful. But for consistency, we utilize it for each API.

Answer (score 2):

Just like @robotdan said, you must include the `queryString` field inside a `search` property. Although it may not be explicit at a first glance, you can imply that by taking a look at the request body fields:

[Fusion Auth User API screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wXI3W.png)
As you can see in the 3rd row, there is a `search.queryString` where you should define the string you are searching, which in your case is everything (`*`). Also, if you want an ordered list, look at the 6th row that contains the available sort fields and in the 7th row the order of the results: `asc` or `desc` (it does not appear in the screenshot so take a look at the FusionAuth official documentation page).

Imagine you want all users whose name must contain `foo` at any position of them `fullName`, ordered by users `email` in descending order. Your object should be something like this:

```js
const request = {
  search: {
    queryString: '*foo*',
    sortFields: [{ name: 'email', order: 'desc' }]
  }
}
```

Notice the `*` in the beginning and in the end: those asterisks tells the search engine that `foo` may have a prefix and/or a suffix (but you don't care about them).